# Strict part of a relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

What do you mean by the term strict part of a binary relation?

How can it be used to define minimal element for any set with relation?

Comment: Please provide more context.

Comment: @user774025: Maybe it means take out all pairs of the form $(x,x)$?

Comment: Do you mean:"the less strict definition" of the binary relation?

Comment: @user774025,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Strict_and_non-strict_partial_orders

Comment: No, not the less "the less strict definition" of the binary relation. Given a binary relation, you can obtain obtain another binary relation called its strict part by removing some elements from the old binary relation. But I don't exactly which elements are removed.

Comment: example:to get strict part of binary relation that is called partial order ($\leq$) one has to remove such $(a,b)$ pairs where $a=b$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say without more context, but it seems like you are to take out pairs of the form $(x,x)$ from your relation (i.e. dropping the condition of reflexivity). This is similar to how "less than or equal to" gives rise to "strictly less than".

Given a strict relation, you can find a minimal element of a *finite* set by taking a descending chain $x_1 > x_2 > \cdots > x_n$. Since the set is finite, the chain will indeed terminate at a minimal element.

If the set is infinite, there may not be a minimal element under every relation. For example, in the real numbers with usual "less than" relation there can be descending chains with no minimal element.

Comment: I haven't heard the term before, but this is what I would immediately assume it means, for precisely the reason given here.